# Copy new files from NAS to External Hard Drive with rsync

Tags: bash, shell, rsync, file-copy

I want to copy new files from my NAS to my external hard drive. I did copy the new files manually up to this point. Now I want to use a script to automate this for me. However everything I tried so far with rsync seems to copy all files and not only the new files.
I tried with the following command:

```bash
rsync -ar \
      --ignore-existing \
      --size-only \
      --progress --info=progress2 \
      --dry-run \
      "/Volumes/NAS" "/Volumes/G-DRIVE mobile SSD R-Series"
```

I also tried without size-only, with checksum etc. Can somebody explain the behaviour to me or what I need to do in order to complete my task? When printing stats it always shows that it would transfer all the files. Also with the -i parameter I get the following information for every file: >f++++++++++

Comment: Ok I quickly checked the metadata and found that the creation date is different f.e "kMDItemContentCreationDate             = 2012-01-28 05:59:13 +0000" vs. "kMDItemFSCreationDate      = 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000". However the size (kMDItemFSSize              = 1170942) seems to be the same and I thought with the size-only option this should work.

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/a/1602023/340330) worked fine for me.

Comment: Thanks I found the solution in the accepted answer from your link. I was missing a trailing slash in the source folder which was causing the problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct command should probably be this:

```
rsync --archive --progress --info=progress2 \
    '/Volumes/NAS/' '/Volumes/G-DRIVE mobile SSD R-Series'
```

The `-a` (`--archive`) flag implies `-t` (`--times`) and `-r` (`--recursive`) so you don't need to specify those explicitly. Using `--size-only` is a poor choice when you have size and timestamp available from using `-a` (`--archive`), but if you're copying to a limited filesystem such as FAT you may need a time window such as `--modify-window=2` to overcome the two second time granularity. You shouldn't use `--ignore-existing` unless you want to ignore changes to the source files once you've got a copy of any sort on the destination.

Definitely use `--dry-run` (`-n`) while testing, but remember to remove it when you're ready for the `rsync` action to be applied.

Finally, the source directory should usually have a trailing slash. The documentation describes it like this,

> A trailing slash on the source changes this behavior to avoid creating an additional directory level at the destination. You can think of a trailing `/` on a source as meaning "*copy the contents of this directory*" as opposed to "*copy the directory by name*".